# UI-Router default view inside div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

Say I have index.html with:

```
<div ui-view="viewA">
    // content
</div>
```

Is it posible to put content inside div that will serve to me as default route? So without including or anything else, just need to put some markup directly in that div.

Comment: Did you try it? What happened? I'd say this entirely depends on if you're using `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aF36amCP1OgCQ5j34ZDo?p=preview)

That is possible, and really pretty easy. So, let's have this inside of index.html

```
<div ui-view="">

  this is the content of ui-view, 
  which serves as a template for a default state

</div>
```

And this could be the default state and otherwise

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/default');

// States
$stateProvider
  .state('default', {
      url: "/default",
  })
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/aF36amCP1OgCQ5j34ZDo?p=preview)

Comment: This does not work when default content is an iframe.