# AngularJS - Default view in <ui-view> element

Tags: angularjs

Is there any problem putting default code inside of a `<ui-view>` element. It appears to work, but I can't find anything saying one way or another if it's okay to use or not.

My current usage is I want the "default" view to be a list of items. Upon clicking one of those items, it switches to an "editor" child state, which replaces the `<ui-view>` content with the editor child.

Are there any gotchas I should be aware of before continuing with this approach?

Here is an example of what I'm looking at:

routes.js:

```
.config(($stateProvider) => {
    $stateProvider
        .state('admin', {
            url: '/admin',
            templateUrl: 'admin.html'
        })
        .state('admin.items', {
            url: '/admin/items',
            templateUrl: 'admin.items.html'
        })
});
```

admin.html:

```
<ui-view>Default Stuff Here</ui-view>
```

items.html:

```
<p ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</p>
```

Now, I know I can do:

```
.state('admin.default', {
    url: '',
    templateUrl: 'admin.default.html'
});
```

And then put that would show in `ui-view`. However, that needlessly adds a new state and template file, when it seems to work just fine putting the would-be contents of `admin.default.html` directly into the `ui-view` of `admin.html`.

In my case, I'm not talking about a completely stateless option using `otherwise()`, I'm talking about a defined parent state with a default child state.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UI-Router default view inside div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37648492/ui-router-default-view-inside-div)

Comment: It looks like it is a duplicate, though it never got a super satisfactory answer. It said you could, which I know, but I don't know if it's good or bad to do so.

Comment: @Phil Actually, upon closer looking, it isn't a duplicate of the one you mentioned. The other revolves around using the `otherwise()` function. My question resolves around default content of a defined parent state. I've expanded my question to clarify.

Comment: There is nothing particlularly *wrong* with this approach, but it's not the accepted norm.  Aside from the inconsistency of having certain content processed differently (which can be difficult to troubleshoot), you could have issues with your default data displaying for brief periods when a new state is loaded, particularly when using `resolve`.  Also, there is potential for issues with layout/styling.

Answer (score 0):

We generally do not put anything inside `<ui-view></ui-view>`, instead we create a default state and use that.

```
routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

     $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'home.html'
        })

        .state('about', {
            // we'll get to this in a bit       
        });

});
```

Here the default one is `/home`, like that you can create a default one.

Comment: I know that's an approach I can do again, but since, in my particular use-case, it adds lots of extra template files for no particular reason (the existing template files are pretty much just a `<ui-view></ui-view>` to begin with. Do you have any official or well-respected sources that refer to one approach or another? Thanks.

Comment: If you are keeping the default data in ui-view, i have a concern, will it be available, if you want to go back to default content from some other states.

Comment: I've updated my post to show a more complete example of what I'm talking about. Really what I'm talking about is putting HTML inside of the <ui-view> instead of making a new state and template file with a url of `""`

Comment: One of the issues is that the default content is visible upon page refreshing

Answer (score 0):

**First,** As said in the other answer, we never give any data within the ui-view.. But while dealing with the ui-router, you should give all the specific states in .config()

```
app.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
$stateProvider
.state('home',{
     url : '/home',
     controller: 'homeCtrl',
     templateUrl : 'home.html'
}).state('login',{
     url : '/login',
     controller: 'loginCtrl',
     templateUrl : 'login.html'
});

//AND HERE YOU PROVIDE THE DEFAULT PLACE WHERE THE USER IS TO BE REDIRECTED
//IN CASE OF IMPROPER URL

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
});
```

**Secondly,** If you want to use the `<ui-view></ui-view>` to hold some data, you certainly can put some data within them.. But make sure that from the state you define, It should not supply any `template` or `templateUrl`. So the data within the `<ui-view></ui-view>` stays as it is.

**And third..** Why to keep a default state..

in case you are defining a **state** admin in your `config()`, and then in your **admin.routes.js** file you can define a state as follows..

```
.state('admin.login',{
url:'',
controller:'loginCtrl',
templateUrl:'admin.login.html'
});
```

So in case the url is `YOURURL/admin`  It will directly open the login page by default.. so there is no chance of redundancy...

Comment: I've updated my post to show a more complete example of what I'm talking about. Really what I'm talking about is putting HTML inside of the <ui-view> instead of making a new state and template file with a url of `""`

Comment: in that case, cant you not put the default content into the template : "DEFAULT CONTENT" of new state instead of putting it inside the <ui-view></ui-view> ? @samanime

Comment: Yes, I CAN put it there. However, I'd rather not do so, because it creates an extra state and template file, which both seem unnecessary and redundant. What I'd like to know is if there is anything definitively problematic about putting it in the ui-view. I haven't been able to find anything "official" one way or another to answer that question.

Comment: Yes the last thing I can say is that, withing the admin.html, you can write your code within <ui-view></ui-view> but do not supply anything into it from your admin state. This will keep the data as it is on your page. And that data will be overwritten when anything is supplied to that ui-view by template or templateUrl..  Because myself had a problem dealing with it and write withing <ui-view> to show the LOADING.. spinner.. It will stay as it is untill it is supplied by some html @samanime